# Visual Studio 2015. How to find less files with specific classes

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, findstr

I was wondering if there was an easy way, in Visual Studio 2015, to "navigate to" a less-file in a solution containing a specific css-style?

If I use the search-function (ctrl+f) or find-in-files (ctrl+shift+f) I also find occurances in the css-files. Not optimal.

I have my less files in  a separate folder in my project. What I would really like to do is to search a specific sub-folder. To achieve this now, I have to right-click the folder, open a command prompt and use `findstr` to search the less files.

Is there an easier way to do this in Visual Studio 2015? Are there any extensions available that can do this? I tend to need this function quite often.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Are there any extensions available that can do this?" - yes, Entrian Source Search can do all of this; see http://entrian.com/source-search/

It lets you include or exclude specific file types and/or directories from your search, so you could search for `.my-css-style ext:less dir:myfolder` (specifying both `ext:` and `dir:` might be overkill in this situation, but both features are there).

It builds an index for your code (so searches are fast) and you can exclude certain files or directories from the index.  In your case, you might want to exclude the generated `.css` files so they are never found by a search - only the source `.less` files would be in the index.

<sub>(Discosure: Entrian Source Search is a commercial product and I wrote it.)</sub>